# How do I get rid of mid spaces in an environment variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

How do I get rid of mid spaces in an environment variable?

Suppose I have the following `for` loop fragment that get the free disk space size of a certain disk.

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ('dir ^| find "Dir(s)"') do set size=%%i
```

would result something like this

```
C:\>set size=129,028,096
```

I would like to get rid of delimeters as follows.

```
for /f "delims=," %%i in ('echo %size%') do set size=%%i
```

and resulted something like this

```
set size=129 028 096
```

How can I get it with no mid spaces or delimiters with native tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
set size=%size: =%
```

afterwards which will replace all spaces with nothing.

But you can also do that with commas :)

But keep in mind that (a) the delimiter changes, it's a dot for me, not a comma. That may depend on your OS language or regional settings. And (b) you can't really do math with that value afterwards as `cmd` is limited to signed 32-bit math (using `set /a`).

Your second `for` statement won't work properly, by the way, since it will just set `size` to the last digit group. That can be circumvented but I'd rather advise to use the replacing directly on commas/dots:

```
set size=%size:,=%
set size=%size:.=%
```

Comment: Thanks alot thats outstanding can i do it in one step

Comment: Less than two lines probably not. But that should be short enough. You can try to use tokenizing and then just concatenate each token, but depending on your HDD size that may result in one token more or less ... certainly not ideal. I'd go with your first line and then replace all commas.